# How to modify Object in Dependency Injection Pattern

Tags: ios, swift, oop, dependency-injection, pass-by-reference

So for the time I worked on the project and avoided Singletons and used Dependency Injection. By this I mean instead of creating a shared instance I created a class instance and passed to all controllers whichever needs.

Now my question, my model object which has references in all controllers, I need to point them either to a new object as for the requirements the data is fully updated like calling the `init()` again.

But if I do that in a certain controller that reference will only point to this new object.

So if you get what I mean I want the pointee of the references or where at memory address that object is there should be replaced to a new one and all references should still point to that old address / new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to inject not model in controllers, but service for obtaining and saving this model, something like this.

Protocol for service:

```
protocol ModelServiceProtocol {
    func obtainModel(completion: (Model) -> Void)
    func save(model: Model, compleiton: ()->Void)
}
```

Example ViewController with dependency:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let modelService: ModelServiceProtocol

    init(modelService: ModelServiceProtocol) {
        self.modelService = modelService
    }

    func obtainModel() {
        modelService.obtainModel { model in
            // do something
        }
    }

    func saveEditedModel() {
        modelService.save(model: model) {
            // model saved
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of ModelService that will obtain and save your model:

```
class ModelService: ModelServiceProtocol {
    func obtainModel(completion: (Model) -> Void) {
        // implementation of obtainig model from some storage
    }

    func save(model: Model, compleiton: ()->Void) {
        // implementation of saving model in some storage
    }
}
```

Injection of dependency:

```
func buildController() -> ViewController {
    let modelService = ModelService()
    let viewController = ViewController(modelService: modelService)
    return viewController
}
```

In this approach you will get actual model in ViewController, edit and save to some storage. Model will be actual on every step

Comment: Okay, I see it's a nice way instead of multiple references everywhere now there is only one reference to model. And if I mutate through ModelService class it will always point the new everywhere. But still if let say I did mutate in some controller and navigate back to home / dashboard. I still need to refresh UI and call APIs. I think then I also need to add a didChange observer to ModelService class? And does my controllers will observe it? Thanks for the solution it's very organized.

Comment: I also came across this called Model Controllers, something similar to yours: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/model-controllers-in-swift

Comment: Yes, you can add some func for subscribing on model changing or you can update  your model when viewController did appear